# HTML documentation build issue with Wolfram Workbench 2 and MMA 9

Tags: version-9, workbench

Using the Wolfram Workbench 2 (and Mathematica 9) to build HTML documentation for a package I am developing, I am ending up with HTML pages that contain a lot of text elements that look like this:

> Div[{class -> MCap}, {Change a few exchange reaction flux bounds to reflect an aerobic minimal glucose medium.}]

or

> Div[{}, {XMLElement[a, {href -> javascript:input('i_9'), onmouseover -> javascript:return(true);}, {XMLElement[img, {src -> Files/Constraint-based modeling/I_10.gif, height -> 35, width -> 447, alt -> Click for copyable input}, {}]}]}]Div[{name -> i_9_out, id -> i_9_out, class -> IFL}, {}]

It looks a lot like a shadowing error and indeed a new `Div` function has been introduced to Mathematica 9. Is there a way to work around this for the moment? The HTML documentation builds fine with Mathematica 8.

Answer (score 4):

The Documentation Tools in Workbench 2.0 haven't been updated yet to work properly with Mathematica 9, so the easiest workaround is to use Mathematica 8 to build your HTML pages.

However, if this isn't a option for whatever reason, you could try to modify the code of Documentation Tools in order to solve this particular issue. I haven't tested the following, but I suspect there's a high chance it might work.

The culprit in your case is the file `/Transmogrify/Kernel/Transmogrify.m`, which can be found in the directory `DocumentationBuild`, whose value can in turn be read of from the first few log lines of a doc build in WorkBench. In `Transmogrify.m`, change the line

```
Div[ attr_List:{}, cont_ ] := TagElement["div", attr, cont];
```

(found at line number 2588) to

```
Unprotect[Div];
Div[ attr_List:{}, cont_ ] := TagElement["div", attr, cont];
Protect[Div];
```

Let me know if this did the trick!

Comment: It worked for me (Mathematica v9.0.1, Workbench 2.0), but all the links point to the web (reference.wolfram.com), so none of them really work.

Comment: @QuantumDot You can fix them by adding [this Teake's code](https://github.com/xAct-contrib/xTras/blob/91cfe93a65cb15fdf5fa2826193b2e8a3312b037/buildfiles/documentation.xml#L114-L122) to your `createHTML` target in `docbuild.xml`. It's also implemented in [WWBCommon](https://github.com/jkuczm/WWBCommon).